# PayPal ExpressCheckout - UK specific API?

Tags: paypal

I've been asked to extend a US-based site that is using ExpressCheckout to the UK. Is there any difference in the API being used?

I've looked through the PayPal developer site, I can see there is a different UK API for  Website Payments Pro - https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks#PayflowPro , but we're not using that.

The only possible reference I can find about ExpressCheckout localisation is to specify the currency - https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECSimpleIntegration#id0832BA0605Z . Is that the only configuration required, as I've heard some horror stories about people trying to build UK-based PayPal api calls in the past

thanks

Toby

Comment: There is no difference between Website Payments Pro for the US and the UK. What you're referring to with the first link is 'Website Payments Pro UK Payflow Edition'; this is a legacy product which is no longer directly for sale. Both US and UK merchants use the DoDirectPayment API nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no changes. You only need to change the currency.
This is not really a programming question though.

Comment: it would have been a programming job for me if there was a difference!  Cheers.